# GET call not working with JQUERY using an AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can anyone see a problem with this? It was working but now 'genitive' comes back as undefined and the url doees not seem to be getting executed.  The call is passed the ID of a constellation for example **42 = Hydra**, the call should return the genitive which is **Hydrae**.

```js
function updateSN(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var e = document.getElementById("frm_GreekID");
  var gid = e.value;
  var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  var cons = document.getElementById("frm_Constellation");
  var ctxt = cons.value;
  alert("CVAL = " + ctxt);
  $.ajax({
    url: "ggenitive.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      c: ctxt,
    },
    success: function (response) {
      // show response for success
      let genitive = response.value;
      alert("GENITIVE = " + genitive);
      document.getElementById("frm_StarName").value = gid + " " + genitive;
    },
  });
}
```

in the ggenitive.php page I get the correct response when changing the $_POST to $_GET and passing the constellation value in the url, i know the function is getting called because the alert boxes work.

Here is the ggenitive.php if this helps

```php
<?php
require( '../db_connect.php' );
include( '../inc/tvms_inc.php' );
//var_dump($_POST);
session_start();
$qga = "SELECT cGenitive FROM `ast_cons` WHERE id = '".$_POST['c']."'";
$rga = mysqli_query( $conn, $qga )or die( "<div class='container'><table class='table'><tr><th>COULD NOT PERFORM QUERY [GENITIVE]</th></tr><tr><td>" . $qga . "</td><tr>" . mysqli_error( $conn ) . "</td></tr></table></div>" );
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rga);
echo $row['cGenitive'];
?>
```

Comment: So just a suggestion, if you are sending data to backend which doesn't change/affect the db and the data being sent is not sensitive, you should use GET request. In your case if it's just a plain select statement, then use a GET request.

Comment: Also you don't need `var e` instead just `var gid = document.getElementById("frm_GreekID").value` similar for `var cons` and remove if unused variable `var text`. And on your php side, you are prone to SQL injections use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Use short and descriptive variable names of item they are storing or what they are/meant to do on both sides, for example reading this `<td>" . $qga . "</td>` causes a question "**Wait what is this `$qga ` var again?**"

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> let genitive = response.value;
> ```

Your response is a plain string which does not have a `value` property.

You can just use the plain string response directly

```js
success: function(genitive) {
  alert("GENITIVE = " + genitive);
  document.getElementById("frm_StarName").value = `${gid} ${genitive}`;
}
```

---

I would also recommend using some modern practices for your server-side code. Namely using prepared statements and responding with appropriate status codes in case of errors

```php
<?php
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'c', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
// use `INPUT_GET` if passing parameters in the query string

if (!$id) {
    http_response_code(400);
    exit('Invalid "c" value');
}

// throw exceptions
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

require __DIR__ . '/../db_connect.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../inc/tvms_inc.php'; // what does this one do?

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `cGenitive` FROM `ast_cons` WHERE `id` = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($cGenitive);
if (!$stmt->fetch()) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit("ID $id not found");
}

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $cGenetive;
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, will update my php, thanks